# Curiously recurring template pattern. No matching function for call to.. template argument/substitution failed

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, g++, crtp

I am trying to implement the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern in C++, but I can't make it work. Can someone point out what is wrong with my code?

```
template <typename T>
struct Base {
    int x;
    Base():x(4){}
};

struct Derived: Base<Derived> {
    Derived(){}
};

template<typename H>
void dosomething(Base<H> const& b) {
    std::cout << b.x << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    Derived k();
    dosomething(k);
}
```

I am trying to keep the signature of dosomething as it is, so that any class that implements the methods in Base can be used in dosomething().

This is the error I am getting:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
In function ‘int main()’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘dosomething(Derived (&)())’
note: candidate: template<class H> void dosomething(const Base<H>&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types ‘const Base<H>’ and ‘Derived()’
```

Why am I getting this error? Isn't the compiler supposed to treat k as a const reference when invoking dosomething()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the result of vexing parse. This declaration:

```
Derived k();
```

is a function. You should use `Derived k;` or `Derived k{};`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Derived k(); // function declaration
```

it is a function declaration, which takes no parameters and return `Derived` object.
And compiler error tells you about it by

```
no matching function for call to ‘dosomething(Derived (&)())
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

try

```
 Derived k; // instance of object
 dosomething(k);
```